# How to share data and calculations across multiple controllers in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

This is my first project using AngularJS and, unfortunately, it isn't exactly a gentle introduction. I have had to "hit the ground running" so to speak.

I am tasked with building a customizable survey form where the question definitions are loaded from the DB. I have managed to get this working, for the most part, thanks to [this angular-dynamic forms project](https://bitbucket.org/danhunsaker/angular-dynamic-forms). I now need to add weighted scoring to the survey questions so that the survey answers can generate an overall score.

My data structure basically looks like the following:

```
[{
    "title": "Survey title",
    "active": true,
    "form": {
        "FocusQuestions": {
            "type": "fieldset",
            "title": "Focus area",
            "scoreWeight": 30,
            "fields": [{
                "AgeGroup": {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "What is the age group?",
                    "options": {
                        "1": "Infants (0 - 2yrs)",
                        "2": "Toddlers (2 - 4yrs)",
                        "3": "Children" (4 - 13yrs)"
                    },
                    "maxScore": 3
                }
            }
       }
   }
   "responses":[{
       "name": "John Doe",
       "answers":{
           "AgeGroup": 2
       }
   }]
}]
```

In my code, I have a SurveyController which is in charge of loading the survey definition, etc and a ResponseController which is in charge of tasks related to the actual survey responses. What I am having trouble figuring out is the proper "angular way" of combining the response answers with the scoring weights defined in the surveys to generate the scores. Because there are two controllers that need to share data, I suspect I may need something like a ScoringService which does all of the tallying, but I cannot wrap my head around how it would work. Any help or guidance you could offer me would be well appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the hard part of using angular I do not see any code here?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path! Using a "ScoringService" would be the correct way to implement it.

Services are just objects that can be shared across various controllers. The way you would create a service is by using the "service" method on your app module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.service('serviceName', function(){
   this.tally = function(scores){  
     // Do some tallying and return result
   }
});
```

You can call the service from your controller by injecting it into the function:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function(serviceName){
   // now you can invoke the tally function within your controller by doing:
   serviceName.tally(scores)
});
```